# need to get data from a database nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a server that is written in Java running Rhino for js,
and I decide to rewrite this server into nodejs... 
And I need to get data from DB synchronous like :

```
function executeRowsetParam(sql, p){
return DB.raw(sql,p)// returns object
}
```

so I can use it like :

```
var userName = executeRowsetParam('SELECT user_name FROM users where user_id = ?', ["123"]);

if(userName.getRow(0).getValue("user_name ") == "admin"){
//do sth
}
```

is just an a simple example sometimes I need to select from database data that i have to use in like 1000 lines of code so code like :

```
executeRowsetParam('SELECT user_name FROM users where user_id = ?', ["123"]).then((r)=>{
if(r.getRow(0).getValue("user_name ") == "admin"){
//do sth
}
})
```

won't work so well ... 
I have code like this too:

```
IfExists(SQL,p){
if(DB.raw("selecect top 1 1 from" + sql,p) == 1){
return true
}else{return false}
```

and rewriting it into :

```
DB.raw("selecect top 1 1 from" + sql,p).then((r)=>{
if(r == 1){//do sth}else{//do else} 
})
```

won't work for me 
so is there some npm package that I can use to make selects from db synchronuch that would make my day.

is code like this would be okey ?

```
    var Start = async () => {
var Server = require("./core/server/Server");
console.log('hi!');
console.dir("there is nothing to look at at the momment");
var db = require("./core/db/DB");
global.DB = new db()

 function foo() {
    return DB.executeSQL("asdasd", [123, 123])
}
console.dir(await foo());
console.dir('asd');
global.DEBUG = true;
global.NEW_GUID = require('uuid/v4');

var server = new Server()
server.start();
}
Start();
```

is that enough to let me use await in every single instance inside the server or have I make every single function async if I would use await?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question, but if you're just looking for a way to interact with a DB synchronously, you should try await/async.

Comment: added example with async/await

Comment: No - you'd make your DB lookup functions async (so they would need to return a Promise<Result>), and then the calling code can just do let result = await lookupFunction(...).  If you're new to async/await, there are loads of tutorials if you google it.

Comment: okey i'll look at them thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and tested [deasync](https://github.com/abbr/deasync)  works great!

```
var deasync = require('deasync');

module.exports = function DB(){
  var knex = require('knex')(require("./../../config").DB);

  this.executeRowsetParam = (sql, param) => {
    let done = false;
    knex.raw(sql, param).then((r => {
      done = r;
    })).catch((e => {
      throw "Error in query "+ e
    }))
    deasync.loopWhile(function () { return !done; });
    return done
  }
}
```